# Using JAXB @XmlValue with @XmlElementRef

Tags: jaxb

Is it possible to use @XmlValue annotation on a referenced object annotated with @XmlElementRef?  The goal is to produce the following XML output:

```
    <foo>
       <bar>Blah</bar>
    </foo>
```

Given the following example JAXBContext initialization is throwing a NPE:
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)

**Foo Class**

```
     @XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
     public class Foo
     {
         @XmlElementRef
         private Bar bar;
     }
```

**Bar Class**

```
     @XmlRootElement(name = "bar")
     public class Bar extends BarBase // BarBase is annotated with @XmlTransient
     {
         @XmlValue
         private String value;
     }
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired output based on the implementation? I've been looking into Adapters, but haven't been successful at implement one.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**JAXB RI Issue Confirmed**

I have been able to confirm the issue you are seeing with the JAXB RI.  I get the following stack trace:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1148)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:445)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at forum14490548.Demo.main(Demo.java:10)
```

This is a bug in the [**JAXB RI**](http://jaxb.java.net/) and I would recommend opening a ticket at the following link:

- http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/

**Option #1 - Use an Alternate Mapping with JAXB RI**

The following mapping appears to work with the JAXB RI (using `@XmlElement` instead of `@XmlElementRef`.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
public class Foo
{
    @XmlElement
    private Bar bar;
}
```

**Option #2 - Use an Alternate JAXB (JSR-222) Provider**

Your mappings are correct.  If you use another [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider such as EclipseLink MOXy you will not get this exception.  Below is a link that explains how to use MOXy as your JAXB provider:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Answer (score 1):

@blaise - as a workaround create an optional `@XmlAttribute` or `@XmlElement` within the `Bar` class

Answer (score 0):

I'm here for exactly the same issue. This issue is still alive with `1.8.0_77`.

I bypassed with an additional dummy attribute as `user3345125` mentioned.

```
@XmlAttribute
public String getNothing() {
    return null;
}
```

For anyone would like to trace. https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/1027